# How to create dynamic properties in SPFX

Tags: spfx, property

I have a dropdown control showing all document library names. Once the document library is selected, I have to create one one filter for each column and add a control in config pane dynamically. I am not sure how many columns are there and it may vary. Please see the below code.

```
 protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {

    if (propertyPath == 'libraryName' && newValue) {
        //Getting the column info here.
        //How to add the dynamic property here??

    }
 }
```

I am new to SPFX, would appreciate if you can guide in this case. Want something like 
https://github.com/spplante/react-content-query

or 'Highlighted Content' Web Part